# SSRS Chart in tablix with Column Break

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-grouping

I wanted to create a multicolumn report with paging. For complexity I have Gauge control in first row and Chart control in second row.

I have data from table like this

MetricID | ColumnNo | RowNo 
   1         |
   1            |
   1         
   2         |
   2            |
   1         
   3         |
   3            |
   1         
   4         |
   1            |
   2

I have created a parent row group on RowNo and parent Column Group on ColumnNo.

So it suppose to shows First three records on First page and other one record on next page.
For the first page it does what is expected.as shown below. 
**Page 1**
**COL1**      |  
**COL2**    |  
**COL3** 
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
 Gauge1  | Gauge2   | Gauge3 
 Chart1    | Chart2     | Chart3

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

but on second page it again shows me three columns. First column with proper data and the other two columns with no data. as shown below 
**Page 2**
**COL1**      |
**COL2**               |  
**COL3** 
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
 Gauge4  | Empty Gauge   | Empty Gauge 
 Chart4    | Empty Chart     | Empty Chart

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Why this two columns gets generated on Page 2 since there is no data returning from procedure? and how can I remove those unwanted columns?

As I am a new to this blog I am not able to upload screenshot. But this is what I can explain.
Can anyone please suggest anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much research I understood that SSRS will generate those two columns from cache data. So even if there is no data, it will return me the value. In that case Null checking is also not possible.
So I created extra records having default value for my check and hide columns conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

set the column visibility based on the null value in the empty column.